# Get X/Y Coordinates on Button using 'onclick' and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, coordinates

I am a JavaScript beginner and am looking for a way to get the x and y coordinates on a button when it's clicked.  This works in Opera, IE9 and Chrome but I can't get it to work in Firefox.  Here is my code so far:

Function in JavaScript:

```
function buttonClick(subEvent)
{
    var mainEvent = subEvent ? subEvent : window.event;

    alert("This button click occurred at: X(" +
    mainEvent.screenX + ") and Y(" + mainEvent.screenY + ")");
}
```

Here is the HTML section:

```
<input type="button" onclick="buttonClick()" value="Submit"/>
```

The idea here is to only get the coordinates when the button is clicked and to get the actual coordinates within the border of the button itself.  Getting coordinates on the screen is easier and finding that solution for all browsers was already accomplished.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: um you don't get an X and Y as a child element of TD the X and Y positions are governed by the table layout

Comment: I think that just placed the button itself inside a table.  To be clearer, I removed that code section...  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to pass on the event. This is done as so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="buttonClick(event)" value="Submit"/>
                                            ^
                                            '---- that one there
```

Comment: Damn!  See, this is a great example of a plain 'ol misunderstanding.  I actually read this somewhere else, but the example made it seem like the 'event" was the variable, so I placed mine in place of 'event' like so `onclick="buttonClick(subEvent)"` and it didn't work.  But you actually need the word 'event' in there...  Geez...  Thanks!