# X/Y Detection and Submission onClick of a JavaScript Link?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a page where people can battle one another on my game and, the attacks are JS Links, so.. to help catch cheaters I would like to make it so that on the click of the attack, it submits the X/Y coords of where they clicked on the link into the database.

Could someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: What does your code so far look like?

Comment: Let me show you one of the Attack Links.

function attackONE() { 
window.location = "";
}

Thats what I have but I took out the location, I want to make it so that on the click of that, it gets the x/y and submits it into my database.

Comment: That leads to the damage etc thats dealt, etc..

Im trying to just finish this by adding that X/Y thing so that I can catch cheaters. o:

Comment: question is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797468/get-x-y-coordinates-on-button-using-onclick-and-javascript, which will get yor coords

Comment: I dont want to just get the coords, i want it to add them into the Database, thats the trouble im having.

Comment: what database are you using?, and when the user clicks attackONE() would you like the request (coord) sent via say ajax.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code can help you, after this you can send the position with AJAX to your controller....

Info: just click an then refresh the page...

BIG NOTE: dude, please try making your questions in a better way.

SQL table like this:

mysql> create database testpos;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> CREATE TABLE points ( ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, X INT , Y INT,  PRIMARY KEY (ID) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

PHP code: (query_pos.php)

```
<?php
    $link = mysql_connect('mysql_server', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //echo 'Connected successfully';

    mysql_select_db("testpos", $link);

    if( "save" == $_REQUEST['cmd'] ){

        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO points (X,Y) VALUES ( %d, %d );",
            mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['x']),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['y']));

        if (!mysql_query($query,$link)){
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "1 record added";
    }else
    if( "getall" == $_REQUEST['cmd'] ){
        $query = sprintf("SELECT X,Y FROM points");
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if (!$result) {
            $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
            $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
            die($message);
        }

        $xy = "";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $xy .= "X: ".$row['X']." Y: ".$row['Y']."<br>";
        }

        mysql_free_result($result);
        echo $xy;
    }
    mysql_close($link)
?>
```

HTML code: (pos.html)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>-</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        document.onclick=saveMouseCoordinates;

        function saveMouseCoordinates(event){
            ev = event || window.event;
            var x = ev.pageX;
            var y = ev.pageY;

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "query_pos.php",
               data: "cmd=save&x="+parseInt(x)+"&y="+parseInt(y),
               success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
               }
            });
            return true;
        }

        function getPoints(){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "query_pos.php",
               data: "cmd=getall",
               success: function(msg){
                    $("#mouseCoord").html(msg);
               }
            });
            return true;
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="getPoints()">
    <div id="mouseCoord">Mouse Coordinates position will be displayed here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I already know how to get the X/Y, is there a way that it could be Inserted into the database?

Like for example, lets say you click a link, once its clicked, it inserts the x/y coords of where you clicked into PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: mmm something like this??? html click -> js send x - y pos -> php save data into db -> display data in html template

Comment: Yeah!
I basically have everything done, I just need to add the javascript grabbing of the x/y and then submitting it into the database! :D

Basically, its a battle pages, you click the Link (which is javascript) that gets you to the page where the damage etc is done, before that or even on that page, I want to add the X/Y coords of the onClick from the attack you press so that I can check the Battle Logs (x/y) to see if people cheat or not. :D

Comment: ok, give me a sec, to write the code... it'll be ugly (because of the time) but I hope that solve your problem.

Comment: So for the "onClick" do i put "saveMouseCoordinates" or "getPoints"? o: